# Create a view table in MySQL but read data from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, view

I have 2 tables and need to make a **View** table

These are 2 tables that I have:

1. **user** table with some fields: id, username, email, pass
2. **system_log** table with 2 fields: uid, message (uid means user_id)

Now, I'd like to have a **view table** which gives me a table with 2 fields, **username** and **message**.

Here is my problem: I need **username** from **user** table in my **view** table while I have **uid** in my **system_log** table. Basically, instead of having **uid**, I need the **username**

The project and list of fields in the actual project are more than these but I just made it simple here to make my points clear.

Comment: I think you need to learn about `JOIN`.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: Thank you so much, I know Join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `inner join` to get the data from both tables

```
CREATE VIEW `view_name` AS
    SELECT 
        u.user_name, 
        s.message
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN system_log s ON u.id = s.user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS 
SELECT u.username, s.message FROM 
user u INNER JOIN system_log s 
ON u.id = s.user_id
```